# Ruby Regexp gsub, replace instances of second matching character

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I would like to replace the first letter after a hyphen in a string with a capitalised letter.

"this-is-a-string" should become "thisIsAString"

```
"this-is-a-string".gsub( /[-]\w/, '\1'.upcase )
```

I was hoping that \1 would reinsert my second character match  \w and that I could capitalise it.

How does one use the \0 \1 etc options?

Comment: But you did not capture `\w`.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm very new to ruby and regexp - what do you mean by capture?

Comment: Any part of the pattern enclosed within a pair of unescaped parentheses form a capturing group. See more details about *capturing groups* in the [*Use Parentheses for Grouping and Capturing*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) section at regular-expressions.info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture `\w` to be able to refer to the submatch.

Use

```
"this-is-a-string".gsub(/-(\w)/) {$~[1].upcase}
# => thisIsAString
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/fujImw)

Note that `$~[1]` inside the `{$~[1].upcase}` block is actually the text captured with `(\w)`, the `$~` is a matchdata object instantiated with `gsub` and `[1]` is the index of the first group defined with a pair of unescaped parentheses.

See more details about *capturing groups* in the [*Use Parentheses for Grouping and Capturing*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) section at regular-expressions.info.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the enclosed brackets capture the \w. What is `$~[1]`?

Comment: The `$~` is the matchdata object, see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/MatchData.html. The index allows accessing the first capturing group contents. The 0th index is the whole match.

Comment: "the `.upcase` is just applied to an octal character represented with `\1`." <-- This would be true only if the string literal was entered with double quotes. With single quotes as in OP's code, it is equal to `"\\1"` which is also the result of its `#upcase` method.

Comment: @HolgerJust: Yes, sorry, that is right, I removed that misleading part from the answer.